# Executable Python Code - Repeated Null Outputs

Tags: python, csv, error-handling

I am relatively new to the world of coding, attempting to do something slightly beyond my ken.
coming to the code, I am trying to run has two parts. The first part is -

```
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2016 11:59:57 AM','%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/31/2016 11:59:53 PM','%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
odtd = datetime.timedelta(seconds=05)
a = []

def tint():
    x = d1
    while  x < d2:
        x = x + odtd
        a.append(x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
    return a

a= tint()
df3 = np.asarray(a)
np.savetxt("Check2.csv",df3,delimiter = ",", fmt = "%s", header = "Date Format")
```

The above code creates a .csv file which has indexed column's row entries every 5 seconds from a start to end date (d1,d2). You can save this file in your working directory and check the output.

Now the 2nd part of the code uses a .csv file (obtained from another source called UCA1) which have index column (%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S) format and a random value in it's 2nd column. In an attempt to run a lookup from "Check2.csv" to "UCA1 Ticks" and store in a column in "Check2.csv", I write the below code -

```
#2nd Part
df1 = pd.read_csv("UCA1 Ticks.csv")
pd.read_csv("UCA1 Ticks.csv",names = ['UCA1 Curncy','Bid/Ask','Value'], parse_dates= ["UCA1 Curncy"])
df3 = pd.read_csv("Check1.csv")
pd.read_csv("Check2.csv")
u = list()
v = list()
w = list()
z = list()
t1 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=01)
len1 = len(df1.index)
len3 = len(df3.index)
r1 = df3.ix[:,0].tolist()
f1 = df1.ix[:,0].tolist()
f2 = df1.ix[:,0].tolist()

def main(z):
    i = 1
    global u
    while i <= len3:
        j = 1
        while j <= len1:
            if time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_year == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_year and time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_mon == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_mon and time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_mday == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_mday and time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_hour == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_hour and time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_min == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_min and time.strptime(r1[i],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_sec == time.strptime(f1[j],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').tm_sec :
                u.append(f2[j])
        #Above if statement compares year, month, day, hour, min, sec and AM/PM
            j = j +1
        for k in u:
            v.append(k)
            w = pd.DataFrame({'v'})
            z.append(w[w.v>0].sum()/w[w.v>0].count())                
        i = i + 1
    return z
```

So the final output from 2nd part of the code values from "UCA1 Ticks" is in the 2nd column of "Check2.csv" file. When I run this code (which is running, you can check it out) I get a null output for list z. Wante to know why this is always happening? I checked my indents and code again, but can't seem to figure out. Please help.

PS - There might be multiple entries in "UCA1 Ticks.csv" and hence added a for loop taking an average between all the values.

Comment: Do you ever call the function `main(z)` that you defined? If not, you never enter that function. You probably should follow some tutorials on coding, to handle much simpler cases than translating .csv data using `pandas` and `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply DainDwarf. The output is still null when I call the function. I was introduced to python using Pandas and Numpy and hence slightly more comfortable.

Comment: How are you calling the main function? Please also post the full error trace you get, if you get any.

Comment: Hey Erol 30..I am slightly confused myself in accurately calling the main function...I need little help on that (calling the function)...

Comment: Also, I am not getting any error message while executing this code. Which confuses me even more!